# Faithful group actions on tuples from algebraic structures

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, universal-algebra

So I am looking for examples of the following phenomenon.

Suppose that $V$ is a variety with a computable equational theory which is not locally finite. Suppose that $G$ is an infinite finitely presented group generated by elements $s_{1},\dots,s_{k}$. Suppose furthermore that $G$ has a polynomial time computable normal form. In other words, there is a function $f:\{w_{1},\dots,w_{k},w^{-1}_{1},\dots,w_{k}^{-1}\}^{*}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ computable in polynomial time such that if $d_{i},e_{i}\in\{-1,1\},a_{i},b_{i}\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ for each $i$, then 
$f(w_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots w_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}})=f(w_{b_{1}}^{e_{1}}\dots w_{b_{v}}^{e_{v}})$ if and only if $s_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots s_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}=s_{b_{1}}^{e_{1}}\dots s_{b_{v}}^{e_{v}}$. Suppose that there is some $n$ along with two matrices of terms
$$(t_{i,j}(x_{1},...,x_{n}))_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq k},(t^{*}_{i,j}(x_{1},...,x_{n}))_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq k}.$$ These terms come from the variety $V$. Then whenever $X\in V,$ define actions 
of $\{w_{1},\dots,w_{k},w^{-1}_{1},\dots,w_{k}^{-1}\}^{*}$ on $X^{n}$
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{j}=(t_{1,j}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}),\dots,t_{n,j}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}))$$ and
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{j}^{-1}=(t_{1,j}^{*}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}),\dots,t_{n,j}^{*}(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})).$$

Then the variety $V$ satisfies the identities
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots w_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{b_{1}}^{e_{1}}\dots w_{b_{v}}^{e_{v}}$$
if and only if $s_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots s_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}=s_{b_{1}}^{e_{1}}\dots s_{b_{v}}^{e_{v}}$, and the 
equational theory of the variety $V$ is axiomatized by the identities of the form
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots w_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot w_{b_{1}}^{e_{1}}\dots w_{b_{v}}^{e_{v}}$$ where $d_{i},e_{i}\in\{-1,1\},a_{i},b_{i}\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ for each $i.$

In this case, the group $G$ acts on $X^{n}$ for each $X\in V$ by letting
$$(x_{1},...,x_{n})\cdot s_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots s_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}=(x_{1},...,x_{n})\cdot w_{a_{1}}^{d_{1}}\dots w_{a_{u}}^{d_{u}}$$
where $d_{i},e_{i}\in\{-1,1\},a_{i},b_{i}\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ for each $i.$

**Examples**

Example 1: The symmetry group $S_{k}$. Suppose that $\tau_{i}=(i,i+1)$. Then we set
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{k})\tau_{i}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},x_{i},x_{i+2},\dots,x_{k}).$$

Example 2: The braid group $B_{k}$ acting on racks and quandles. Suppose that $(X,*)$ is a rack or a quandle (Let us use left-distributivity $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$). Then define
$$(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})\cdot\sigma_{i}=(x_{1},\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i}*x_{i+1},x_{i},x_{i+2},\dots,x_{n}).$$

Example 3: $\mathrm{Aut}(F_{k})$ acting on tuples from groups.

Example 4: Finite direct products of groups.

In the case where the group $G$ is finite or though the conditions I have listed out are otherwise not technically satisfied (for example by the infinite strand braid group $B_{\infty}$ on $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ for each rack $X$), feel free to give an answer anyways if you feel the answer is still interesting yet does not stray from the spirit of the question too much.